# Как извлечь из массива по цикл twig

Tags: twig

есть массив:

```
                           [sky] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [20549] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [info] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [vid] => 413494715
                                                    [name] => 33码内长19.5cm
                                                    [translate] => Длина в пределах 33 ярдов 19,5 см
                                                )

                                            [pidName] => размер
                                        )

                                    [1627207] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [info] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [vid] => 28326
                                                    [name] => 红色
                                                    [image] => //img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i1/2204165630485/O1CN01oLMlLb1FSAglaGBqf_!!2204165630485.jpg
                                                    [translate] => красный
                                                )

                                            [pidName] => Цвет
                                        )

                                )
```

Как пройтись по цикл и извлечь `pidName` сделал так: `{% for sky in sky %} {{sky.pidName}} {% endfor %}` но цикл не работает.

Comment: `for sky in sky` как отличить один `sky` (массив) от другого `sky` (элемент массива) ? И если смотреть на текущую структуру, то должно быть `... in sky.sky`

Comment: @ArchDemon Разделит имена тоже не помогает например `for sky1 in sky`

Comment: Смотрите на второе замечание

Comment: @ArchDemon переменная в `twig` в цикле определяется первым